# How can I use generic type annotations to describe a recursive data type?

Tags: haskell

Here's the function:

```
comboGraph :: [a] -> Int -> [b]
comboGraph _ 0 = []
comboGraph [] _ = []
comboGraph (x:xs) n =
    (buildEdges x xs) : comboGraph xs n
    where   buildEdges h t = (h, comboGraph t (n-1))
```

Ths function takes in a list of type `a`, a number, and returns a list of type `b`. As you can see, though, type `b` is actually a recursive type -- it will be something along the lines of `[(a, [(a, b1)])]`. When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘(a, [b0])’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      comboGraph :: forall a b. [a] -> Int -> [(a, [b])]
    at xxx.hs:15:15
  Expected type: [(a, [b])]
    Actual type: [(a, [(a, [b0])])]
• In the expression: (buildEdges x xs) : comboGraph xs n
  In an equation for ‘comboGraph’:
      comboGraph (x : xs) n
        = (buildEdges x xs) : comboGraph xs n
        where
            buildEdges h t = (h, comboGraph t (n - 1))
```

How do I properly annotate this function?

Comment: You can not capture that in a list, since it would mean that `a ~ [(b,a)]`. You need a *tree*-like datastructure for that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How do i do this in haskell?

Comment: how actually do you want your data to look at? you will need to define a `data` to begin with.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr ideally id like to use generic types `a` and `b`.

Comment: From what your code does, b has no chance to be generic. What problem are you solving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the issue a bit more evident, let's substitute the definition of `buildEdges` in the final case of your definition:

```
comboGraph (x:xs) n =
    (x, comboGraph xs (n-1)) : comboGraph xs n
```

The result of `comboGraph` is supposed to be a list, but one whose elements are pairs that also have a `comboGraph` result (i.e. a list of the same type) within. As the type error you got says, that doesn't work -- it's as if you wanted a list with two tails. The fix is switching to a different data structure that reflects what you are trying to do:

```
-- Feel free to substitute better names.
data Combo a = Empty | Node a (Combo a) (Combo a)
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

`Empty` covers the base cases which used to result in an empty list, while `Node` has one appropriately-typed field for each of the things you want to combine in the recursive case. `comboGraph` then becomes:

```
comboGraph :: [a] -> Int -> Combo a
comboGraph _ 0 = Empty
comboGraph [] _ = Empty
comboGraph (x:xs) n = Node x (comboGraph xs (n-1)) (comboGraph xs n)
```

(Note that `Combo` is actually a binary tree with values on the nodes.)

Answer (score 4):

I like the other answer, and I think you should use it. But it makes some reasoning leaps that require some intuition, and it can be hard to get this intuition without doing things the mechanical way a few times. So in this answer, I will show how to start with a failing definition like the one you have, "turn a crank", and mechanically get a solution that does work. The technique below can be applied to any infinite type error.

You have the following clause (paraphrased slightly):

```
comboGraph (x:xs) n =
    (x, comboGraph xs (n-1)) : {- ... -}
```

Just doing some straightforward type inference reasoning, we can see that `comboGraph` takes a list of some type (from the fact that it pattern matches on `x:xs`) and a number (from the fact that it subtracts one). Let's pick a concrete (monomorphic! but not yet known) type `a` for the list elements and see what we can infer about what it returns.

Well, it clearly returns a list with tuples inside. And the first part of the tuple is just an `a`. What about the second part? The second part of the tuple is... whatever type `comboGraph` returns. So `comboGraph` returns a type `t` satisfying the equation:

```
t = [(a, t)]
```

The only solution to this equation is `[(a, [(a, [(a, [(a, ...)])])])]`. Such infinite types don't exist raw in Haskell. But there is a standard trick to get quite close: use (type-level) recursion by introducing a newtype. We're solving for `t`, but Haskell types have to start with an upper-case letter, so we'll name our solution to this equation `T`.

```
newtype T a = T [(a, T a)] deriving Show
```

Now we don't *quite* have `T a ~ [(a, T a)]`, but we do have an isomorphism: namely, `\(T xs) -> xs :: T a -> [(a, T a)]` and `T :: [(a, T a)] -> T a` are inverses. So now we can write your `comboGraph` definition by exploiting this isomorphism. Let's name the other half of the isomorphism:

```
unT :: T a -> [(a, T a)]
unT (T xs) = xs
```

So:

```
comboGraph (x:xs) n =
    T ((x, comboGraph xs (n-1)) : unT (comboGraph xs n))
```

The base cases have to get wrapped in `T`, as well, of course:

```
comboGraph _ 0 = T []
comboGraph [] _ = T []
```

Try it in ghci:

```
> comboGraph "abc" 3
T [('a',T [('b',T [('c',T [])]),('c',T [])]),('b',T [('c',T [])]),('c',T [])]
```